# Identify the make / manufacturer of this chandelier

Tags: lighting

I was taking down a 20-year-old (est.) chandelier to paint the ceiling, and I broke one of the five glass cones.  I want to replace the cone, but have not located a suitable match, or a viable replacement for all five cones.  I took the mount off the ceiling, but due to some rust from precious water damage (a now fixed leaking roof), the manufacturer label has disintegrated and is obscured.  This item is located in the United States.

There are three labels on the mount:

1. a number which reads "400366" (probably the serial number)
2. a yellow standard Incandescent Fixture label, Issue No. A-40,093
3. the important white label which may read "H........BURG & CO.  Bellv.... LL.....". The initial 'H' might be a 'K' or 'M', the 'v' might be a 'w', the 'LL'  might be 'II' or '11' or even a 'U', but I'm fairly confident of the rest; The extra dots in my overall quote do not represent actual character spaces.

Two photos follow:

1. a shot of the chandelier (missing two cone s; I need was removed to bring to local lighting places to identify replacements)
2. a shot of the interior of the mount, showing the destroyed label.

I would like to know the manufacturer and, if possible, model name.

[image: Interior of mount]

[image: chandelier]

Comment: Does that UL label really have holes in it, or is it just covered in gunk?

Comment: It's all rusted.  I cleaned the rust off the labels and that's the best.  Nothing is covered by rust.

Comment: Tried calling UL and asking if they can ID who made it/what model it is from their files given the issue number?

Comment: Looks like http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/index.htm is they way to go.  I'll look it up after walking the dog.

Comment: The database isn't pulling up any answers for me.

Comment: The UL database online hasn't been very useful for me either -- and it works off the listing number (E-#####) anyway (which is why I suggested giving them a ring on Monday :)

Comment: I called in; I wasn't typing in the correct UL number.  The UL number is on the left side and is eaten away (E-1 something ending in a round-bottomed number).  I called UL and Jim at UL helped me.  It is H. A. Framburg & Co.  E-12305, Bellwood Illinois.  All of this matches up to the missing characters.  Take the credit win ThreePhaseEel.

Comment: 8835 Framburg Lighting Syzygy Five-Light Chandelier; retails $900-1300; HAND BLOWN GLASS - probably going to cost $200 to replace it.  Stupid internal screw was loose and it fell to the side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Moral of the story -- if you have pieces of a UL listing label, the UL folks *can* help!

It turns out the OP wasn't typing the correct UL number into the database -- the E-##### listing number was eaten away by rust. So, I suggested he call UL, and he reached a friendly guy named Jim who was able to figure it out:

> I called UL and Jim at UL helped me. It is H. A. Framburg & Co. E-12305, Bellwood Illinois. All of this matches up to the missing characters.

Furthermore, with that and the serial, he was able to get the model number -- it's Framburg's 8835, or "Syzygy" (don't ask me about the name).

Comment: Hand-blown glass. Called Framburg and they don't deal directly with customers, only through registered dealers, so I called a local store and they are getting me the replacement for around $70.